# How to bind hostname with ip?

Tags: macos, network, dns, vmware

There are 2 VMs running on VMWare on a remote server. For instance: devops-01 and devops-02. Both of them have SSH access enabled.
To access to the first one I do: `ssh dev@devops-01`. For the other one: `ssh dev@192.168.80.y` (`y` sometimes changes).

Normally I only used devops-01 and rarely the other one. Today, it all changed. Ideally I would like to access both VMs like this: `ssh dev@devops-<ID>`. But, I'm sure that involves calling the server guy and he's on vacations. So, I thought in "switching" my VMs settings.

I copied all the settings from `System Preferes > Network > Ethernet` from the devops-01 and pasted them to the devops-02 corresponding settings. (IP, Subnet Mask, Router, DNS Server, Search Domains are the same).
I also went to `System Preferences > Sharing` and edited the computer name on devops-02. (So now, it says devops-01).
Then, I stoped the *old* devops-01 VM. And now, I have the *old* devops-02 VM running, supplanting devops-01. **BUT** `ping devops-01`says that there is no route to it. Of course it works fine using the ip. But, that's not my intention.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: One way this can happen is that the VM got a different IP-address (from DHCP?) than is stated in DNS. If you do a `nslookup devops-01`. Do you get the same IP as the IP for the VM?

Comment: @JoachimBratteli, nope.  nslookup devops-01
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.85.45, trying next server
Server:  192.168.85.30
Address: 192.168.85.30#50

** server can't find devops-01: SERVFAIL

Comment: Seems like the IP of devops-01 is not resolved by your DNS-server. Either your IP configuration is pointing at the wrong DNS-server or you need to fix the setup of your DNS-server.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but you'd like a hostname to direct you to a specific IP address of your choice. If so, edit the hosts file located in **/etc/hosts** by adding a line like this below the localhost entry:

*123.45.67.89 devops-01*

Again, correct me if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Yes. I want a hostname to direct to a specific IP. But, doing what you suggest only works in my current computer. If I go to other computer, I'll need to do it again. - Before messing up with my changes, I was able to access it without modifying /etc/hosts.

Comment: But you said it only worked for one of them (devops-1), or did you mean both?

Comment: Yes. I was able to access devops-01 from all the computers in my network. But that was not the case for devops-02. The latter one was a test machine, but now... it should replace the first one.